# Linq nested property

Tags: c#, linq

I have this nested for loop which I'd like to elminate by modifying the original query:

```
foreach (var record in records)
{    
  foreach (var ap in record.approverList)
  {
    var approval = (from c in dataContext.approvals
                    where c.recordId == record.recordId
                    && c.personId == ap.personId
                    orderby c.modified descending
                    select c).FirstOrDefault();

    if (approval != null)
    {
      ap.vote = approval.vote;
    }

  }

}
```

---

**Edit**

Ideally, I want to modify the original query for records, which looks something like this:

```
var records = (
  from record in dataContext.Records
  where record.statusId == RecordStatus.Submitted
).Include(e => e.approverList.Select(d => d.approver))
.ToList()
```

Comment: Should item = record? also where is personId coming from?

Comment: @Maess yes, sorry transcribed it incorrectly

Comment: Is there a navigation property on an approver for all their approvals?

Comment: and personId is constant throughout this loop?

Comment: @arserbin3 yes. sorry, missed that. `personId` should be `ap.personId`

Comment: @Maess not currently, but I can add one.

Comment: It would make it easier for you to unwind this loop if you did.

Comment: One last question: it looks like you may change the value of sp.Vote multiple times, is this the intent?

Comment: @Maess No, we are only touching each approver once. Approver is one to many records. And, one to many approvals (only the last vote should count).

Comment: what are you attempting to do? update the approver.vote value to whatever their latest vote is and save the results to database? or is this just to disable the latest vote counts on a page?  It matters because, if you're not attempting to update the database, how you're currently going about it, is fairly unnecessary.

Comment: sorry typo. "display* the latest vote counts on a page"

Comment: @aserbin3, I don't care about saving to the database, in fact `vote` on approver is an unmapped value. I am just trying to improve the performance of existing code without modifying the api. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with linq, and didn't write the original api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the real issue here is that you're executing a query for every single approval in every single record. You don't want to be doing that.  What you want to be doing is joining your records on the database side with your approvals to create a query of pairs.  Selecting out just the one matching approval from all of the joined approvals can be done with just a simple `let`.

Once you've queried all of the approvals and the approval list from the record that pairs with it, updating each item is simple enough.

```
var query = from record in records
            from recordApproval in record.approverList
            join approval in approvals
            on new { record.recordId, recordApproval.personId } equals
            new { approval.recordId, approval.personId }
            into approvalMatches
            where approvalMatches.Any()
            let approval = approvalMatches.OrderByDescending(a => a.modified)
                .FirstOrDefault()
            select new
            {
                recordApproval,
                approval,
            };

foreach (var result in query)
    result.recordApproval.vote = result.approval.vote;
```

Additionally it's worth noting that you shouldn't materialize `records` into a result set; you should keep it as an unmaterialized query so that the join can happen on the database site of things.

Comment: No, that's not quite right. It's not selecting the personId of approver when selecting the approvals.

Comment: @JacobEggers It was before you edited the question to change it...It's a pretty trivial alteration though

Comment: That looks better, but I'm getting this `Error 2 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.`, Also, anyway to modify the original query to for records that you know of? (I appologize, I am very new to linq queries)

Comment: @JacobEggers Then, as the errors indicate, the types of your columns don't match.  Without knowing what your column types are, I couldn't say which ones don't match.  You'll need to figure out why they are different, and how to convert them to be the same.

Comment: `recordId` on `approval` is nullable. which makes `new { record.recordId} equals new { approval.recordId }` fail, even though ` record.recordId equals approval.recordId` works fine. (It shouldn't be nullable, but I can't change it because bad data causes runtime errors.)

Comment: @JacobEggers So now that you know the problem, you need to determine how to convert the nullable and non-nullable values into a single consistent type.

Comment: Fortunately, approver.recordId is also nullable, so I was just able to use that. Thanks for you help, this seems to work, though it doesn't seem to be providing much of a performance benefit. Any idea on a way set the approver.vote on the initial query for records?

Comment: You don't mutate items when performing a query.  You get data when performing a query.  However, by performing a *single* query instead of performing a query for every approval in every record, it should be *dramatically* better.  Of course, you also need to *not* materialize your records query, as I described in my answer, for the query to be able to be performed in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the desired logic seems to be:

For each approval person of each record, get their latest vote.

The clearest way (readable/maintainable) to accomplish that, and with only one call to the database, would look something like this:

**Note: approvals.recordId should be foreign keyed to record.recordId, or the code is slightly more complex (would require an explicit join)**

```
// get all the latest votes for submitted records
var votes = dataContext.approvals
    .Where(x => x.record.statusId == RecordStatus.Submitted)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.modified) // only the latest vote counts, per person
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.recordID, x.personID })
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

After that, you can utilize the list like so:

```
// this lists all the distinct records
var recordIds = votes.Select(x => x.recordId).Distinct();

// see the votes for each record
foreach(var recordId in recordIds)
{
     var thisRecordsVotes = votes.Where(x => x.recordId = recordID).ToList();
}
```